# MPI blocks execution after send when different workloads associated to a processor are used

Tags: c++, mpi, workload

I am having some problems with an MPI code (written by me to test for another program where different workloads are associated to different processors). The problem is that when I use a different number of processors than 1 or *arraySize*(4 in this case), the program is blocked during *MPI_Send*, in particular when I run
`mpirun -np 2 MPItest`
the program is blocked during the call. I am not using any debugger for now, i just want to understand why it works with 1 and 4 processors, but it does not with 2 processors(2 spots in the array per processor), the code is below:

```cpp
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int rank, size;
    const int arraySize = 4;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    // every processor have a different workload (1 or more spots on the array to send to the other processors)
    // every processor sends to every other processor its designated spots


    int* sendbuf = new int[arraySize];
    int* recvbuf = new int[arraySize];

    int istart = arraySize/size * rank;
    int istop = (rank == size) ? arraySize : istart + arraySize/size;

    for (int i = istart; i < istop; i++) {
        sendbuf[i] = i;
    }

    std::cout << "Rank " << rank << " sendbuf :" << std::endl;
    //print the sendbuf before receiving its other values
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        std::cout << sendbuf[i] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // sending designated spots of sendbuf to other processors
    for(int i = istart; i < istop; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            MPI_Send(&sendbuf[i], 1, MPI_INT, j, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }

    // receiving the full array
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize ; i++){
        int recvRank = i/(arraySize/size);
        MPI_Recv(&recvbuf[i], 1, MPI_INT, recvRank, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }


    // print the recvbuf after receiving its other values
    std::cout << "Rank " << rank << " recvbuf :" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        std::cout << recvbuf[i] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    delete[] sendbuf;
    delete[] recvbuf;

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I am using the tags to differentiate between different spots in the array (maybe that is the problem?)

I tried using different numbers of processors, with 1 processor the program works, also with 4 processors the program also works, with 3 processors it crashes, and with 2 processors the program is blocked. I also tried using MPI_Isend but it doesn't work either (the flag is 0), the modified code with MPI_Isend is below:

```cpp
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int rank, size;
    const int arraySize = 4;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    // every processor have a different workload (1 or more spots on the array to send to the other processors)
    // every processor sends to every other processor its designated spots


    int* sendbuf = new int[arraySize];
    int* recvbuf = new int[arraySize];

    int istart = arraySize/size * rank;
    int istop = (rank == size) ? arraySize : istart + arraySize/size;

    for (int i = istart; i < istop; i++) {
        sendbuf[i] = i;
    }

    std::cout << "Rank " << rank << " sendbuf :" << std::endl;
    //print the sendbuf before receiving its other values
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        std::cout << sendbuf[i] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // sending designated spots of sendbuf to other processors
    for(int i = istart; i < istop; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            MPI_Request request;
            //MPI_Send(&sendbuf[i], 1, MPI_INT, j, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Isend(&sendbuf[i], 1, MPI_INT, j, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
            // control if the send is completed
            int flag = 0;
            MPI_Test(&request, &flag, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            const int numberOfRetries = 10;
            if(flag == 0){ // operation not completed
                std::cerr << "Error in sending, waiting" << std::endl;
                for(int k = 0; k < numberOfRetries; k++){
                    MPI_Test(&request, &flag, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
                    if(flag == 1){
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(flag == 0){
                    std::cerr << "Error in sending, aborting" << std::endl;
                    MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
                }
                
            }
        }
    }

    // receiving the full array
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize ; i++){
        int recvRank = i/(arraySize/size);
        MPI_Recv(&recvbuf[i], 1, MPI_INT, recvRank, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }


    // print the recvbuf after receiving its other values
    std::cout << "Rank " << rank << " recvbuf :" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        std::cout << recvbuf[i] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

  
    //MPI_Alltoall(sendbuf, 1, MPI_INT, recvbuf, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    delete[] sendbuf;
    delete[] recvbuf;

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

with this code, also *-np 4* doesn't work either

Comment: take a piece of paper and write out who is sending to who and with what tag. There is probably some logistics problem. And note that send & recv are blocking so you really have to get your sequence right.

Comment: ```(rank == size)``` can never be true ... rank counts 0, 1, 2, 3 whereas size is 4

Comment: @lastchance that is right, it does not solve the problem of blocking though, and it is irrelevant when -np 2.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Maybe I am misunderstanding how MPI works or how I need to send messages, but if I send more than one message to a single target with different tags (after calling MPI_Irecv since other answers on stackoverflow say to call an asynchronous Irecv before calling the send) the program will block. I have written another program to test two processes sending doubles to each other, when I call a single MPI_Send to each other there is no problem, but when I call two or more consecutive MPI_Send to the same process but with different tags, the program blocks. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `MPI_Send` can block; you have to use `MPI_Bsend` or `MPI_Isend` if you want to do all the sends and then all the receives.

Comment: @DavisHerring I know but that was not the problem in the end, it was a problem of the OpenMPI implementation on my laptop since it seems to not free the buffer after the MPI_Recv . Using MPI_Isend took me to more errors instead when I tried, since the buffer was not free probably.

Comment: What do you mean by “free the buffer”?

Comment: I have seen that some implementations use a buffer for the communication (although it is only a conjecture from what I have read, I do not know if a buffer is used or not). I mean that the recv does not seem to free the communication channel between the two processes, but I do not really know the cause of the issue with certainty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have not received any answer yet to the problem, I want to add some insight of my problem to help some people if they find themselves in the same conditions.

I tested another code to see if the OpenMPI standard on my laptop worked well since there were too many problems that were not wrong for the standard and even examples of code on the internet that won't work on my laptop. I tested the following code, a very simple code that sends a part of an array between two processes:

```cpp
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int rank, size;
    const int arraySize = 5;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    // initialize sendbuf
    int* sendbuf = new int[arraySize];
    for(int iteration = 0; iteration < 3; iteration++){

        if(rank){
            std::cout << "Rank " << rank << " sendbuf :" << std::endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
                std::cout << sendbuf[i] << ", ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

        // first process send first three elements to second process
        if(rank == 0){
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                sendbuf[i] = i;
            }
            MPI_Send(&sendbuf[0], 3, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        } else {
            for(int i = 3; i < 5; i++){
                sendbuf[i] = i;
            }
        }

        // receive the full array with MPI_Wait
        if(rank){
            // second process receive the first three elements from first process
            MPI_Recv(&sendbuf[0], 3, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        }

        // print the full array
        if(rank){
            std::cout << "Rank " << rank << " sendbuf after:" << std::endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
                std::cout << sendbuf[i] << ", ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

        // reset MPI requests and buffers
        for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
            sendbuf[i] = -1;
        }
        
    }

    MPI_Finalize();


}
```

I wanted to see if a single send and a single receive would work in a loop on my laptop, and surprise to me (after two days of trying everything), it is a problem of my laptop and the OpenMPI implementation. I tested this code on a cluster that I have and where the MPI implementation works to see if it was a problem of my hardware or not. The code works on the cluster, but not on my laptop.

To conclude, this is the hardware that I have:

- Kernel: 6.6.1-arch1-1
- arch: x86_64
- bits: 64
- compiler: gcc
- model: Lenovo Legion 7 16IAX7
- processor: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12800HX
- OpenMPI version: 4.1.5-5

This is not a solution but answers my question of why the code was not working.

As pointed out by @GillesGouaillardet , it seems it was a problem of the default network interface used with mpirun, specifying a network interface with no firewall rules seems to be the solution.

Comment: try mpirun --mca pml ob1 --mca pml sm,self ... and see if it helps.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Hi, I tried to run `mpirun --mca pml ob1,sm,self -np 2 a.out` and `mpirun --mca pml sm,self -np 2 a.out` but it does not even run (`mpirun --mca pml ob1 --mca pml sm,self -np 2 a.out` gives me an error saying that mca parameter pml was specified more than one time), what is the correct syntax to try?

Comment: my bad, try `mpirun --mca pml ob1 --mca btl sm,self -np 2 a.out`, if it does not work, try `mpirun --mca pml ob1 --mca btl tcp,self -np 2 a.out`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Ok, I tried with `mpirun --mca pml ob1 --mca btl sm,self -np 2 a.out` but it does not run, while `mpirun --mca pml ob1 --mca btl tcp,self -np 2 a.out` starts but blocks at the second iteration (the same behavior as when I run `mpirun -np 2 a.out` with no additional mapping parameters), so no luck yet

Comment: What do you mean by `it does not run`? for the latter, you might have some firewall running on some of your interfaces. try `mpirun --mca pml ob1 --mca btl tcp,self --mca btl_tcp_if_include eth0 -np 2 a.out` (if needed, replace `eth0` with an interface you **know** is working and has no firewall on it)

Comment: Nice! now it seems to work with `mpirun --mca pml ob1 --mca btl tcp,self --mca btl_tcp_if_include <interface> -np 2  a.out` . So it seems that it was a matter of network interface, I will modify the answer according to this information, @GillesGouaillardet thank you so much, I will keep you updated if something else comes up! Also if you want to write another answer I can accept that as the solution (also if you want to give more information on the problem since I do not know much about how MPI works under the hood). Thanks again!

Comment: Under the hood, the `btl/tcp` component will try using all the available network interfaces, so what likely happens is the first message use the first interface and it works, then the following messages try to use the second and that hangs (typically a routing and/or firewall issue). It is odd that `btl/sm` does not work since it should be easier and give you the best performances. Anyway, glad it works for you!

Comment: About the `btl/sm`, I tried with `mpirun --mca pml ob1 --mca btl sm,self -np 2 a.out` but it crashes immediately. It is not a problem to be a little slower with the communication since the most computation that I will do (in the other project that I am writing and that needs MPI for the passing of some values) will be mostly on the single processors. About the `btl/tcp` , I have docker installed, so maybe that could be part of the problem since it creates some interfaces with firewall rules.

Comment: humm, it should not crash ... any stack trace?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet none, even with a try catch block and the `--get-stack-traces` option in mpirun, it just tries to run for 2-3 seconds and crashes with no output (returns non-zero output also, 1 is the exit code so no information is given)

Comment: you can try `mpirun --mca pml ob1 --mca btl sm,self --mca btl_base_verbose 100 -np 2 a.out` to get some output. note you might have to rebuild Open MPI with `configure --enable-debug ...` in order to display the full logs.

Comment: These are the logs [https://pastebin.com/4J96YJUb](https://pastebin.com/4J96YJUb) , I have not rebuilt OpenMPI so I do not know if it is enough

Comment: Thanks! the logs simply state that `btl/sm` cannot be used, but no reason is provided. I guess rebuilding Open MPI will provide the missing information.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I have read the documentation since I cannot rebuild the package (it is an official package), so I used some debugging parameters, these parameters and the stack-trace is the following [https://pastebin.com/Xx9TePXD](https://pastebin.com/Xx9TePXD)

Comment: These logs do not add value (`btl/sm` cannot be used and `MPI_Init()` fails because there is no available `btl` component). If you have time, you can rebuild Open MPI in your `$HOME` directory (you do not need root permissions), for example `configure --enable-debug --prefix=$HOME/openmpi` and then rebuild your app with Open MPI in `$HOME/openmpi/bin`